# cascading filters

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Evertime I unselect a value from the Master Broker Company it should clear all the selected items of Master Broker Name , how do we do that ?

For example I unseletected Company A the selected Mark tapepos or all selected items in Master Broker Name dropdown should be unchecked and cleared .should be cleared and unchecked on Master Broker Name. Help would be much appreaciated , Thanks.

[image]

--->>>>>

[image]

#html code

```
<div class="report-filter-container">
      <div class="report-select-container">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="full-width">
          <mat-label>Master Broker Company</mat-label>
          <mat-select 
            multiple 
            #selectElemMasterBrokerCompanies
            [(value)]="reportFilter.masterBrokerCompany"
            (selectionChange)="changeFilter('masterBrokerCompany',selectAllMasterBrokerCompanies)">
            <div class="idle-report-select-all-container">
              <mat-checkbox
                #selectAllMasterBrokerCompanies
                color="primary"
                (click)="toggleAllSelectionFilter('masterBrokerCompany',selectElemMasterBrokerCompanies,selectAllMasterBrokerCompanies)">
                  Select All
              </mat-checkbox>
            </div>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let f of filters.masterBrokerCompany" [value]="f.display">
              {{f.display}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      
      <div class="report-select-container">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="full-width">
            <mat-label>Master Broker Name</mat-label>
            <mat-select 
              multiple
              #selectElemMasterBrokerNames
              [(value)]="reportFilter.masterBrokerName"
              (selectionChange)="changeFilter('masterBrokerName',selectAllMasterBrokerNames)"> `
              <div class="idle-report-select-all-container">
                <mat-checkbox
                  #selectAllMasterBrokerNames
                  color="primary"
                  (click)="toggleAllSelectionFilter('masterBrokerName',selectElemMasterBrokerNames, selectAllMasterBrokerNames)">
                    Select All
                </mat-checkbox>
              </div>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let f of filters.masterBrokerName" [value]="f.display">
                {{f.display}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="report-select-container">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="report-filter-container">
      <div class="report-select-container">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="full-width">
          <mat-label>WAG Region</mat-label>
          <mat-select 
            multiple
            #selectElemWagRegions
            [(value)]="reportFilter.wagRegion"
            (selectionChange)="changeFilter('wagRegion',selectAllWagRegions)"> `
            <div class="idle-report-select-all-container">
              <mat-checkbox
                #selectAllWagRegions
                color="primary"
                (click)="toggleAllSelectionFilter('wagRegion',selectElemWagRegions, selectAllWagRegions)">
                  Select All
              </mat-checkbox>
            </div>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let f of filters.wagRegion" [value]="f.description">
              {{f.description}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
```

#ts code

```
changeFilter(filterName:string, selectAll: MatCheckbox){    
    this.isAllSelected[filterName] = (this.reportFilter[filterName].length === this.filters[filterName].length);
    this.payloadFilter[filterName] = JSON.stringify(this.reportFilter[filterName]);
    selectAll.checked = this.isAllSelected[filterName];
  }

  toggleAllSelectionFilter(selectProp: string, selectElem:MatSelect, selectAll: MatCheckbox) {    
    let isSelectAllSelected = this.isAllSelected[selectProp];
    const checkSelAllOption = !isSelectAllSelected;
    selectElem.options.forEach((item: MatOption) => (checkSelAllOption)? item.select(): item.deselect());
    this.isAllSelected[selectProp] = checkSelAllOption;   
    setTimeout(()=>{
      selectAll.checked = checkSelAllOption;
    },0)    
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't be enough setting  `reportFilter.masterBrokerName` to null or empty array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know when a value has been unselected from MasterBrokerName get a reference to the `MatSelect` component and subscribe to `optionSelectionChanges`. Then you can check the `selected` property to filter only changes fired by an unselect action:

```
@ViewChild('selectElemMasterBrokerNames') select: MatSelect;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.select.optionSelectionChanges.subscribe((event) => {
      const { source, isUserInput } = event;
      if (isUserInput && !source.selected) { // Only interested in unselect actions performed by a user
        this.reportFilter.masterBrokerName = null;
      }
    });
 }
```

As for the case when you uncheck "SelectAll" on MasterBrokerCompany I guess you can handle that directly in your `toggleAllSelectionFilter()` function:

```
toggleAllSelectionFilter(
 selectProp: string,
 selectElem: MatSelect,
 selectAll: MatCheckbox
) {
    // ... All your previous code

    setTimeout(() => {
      selectAll.checked = checkSelAllOption;
      if (selectProp === 'masterBrokerCompany' && !selectAll.checked) {
        this.reportFilter.masterBrokerName = null;
      }
    }, 0);
  }
```

Comment: Hi Sir , the current issue whith you code is that when I unchecked the "Select All" it did not clear the data on the master broker Name

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/BoGnvBA

Comment: How about on the ngafterviewinit , we handle bot select and unselect ? cause right it it is just interested on nselect actions performed by a user

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you're asking here. `optionSelectionChanges` will emit any time the control value changes: this can happen because the user selected or unselected the checkbox or because the value was changed programmatically (by your code or by the library). You're filtering the changes you're interested in and in this specific case that will be unselections made by a user.

Comment: It is not clear Sir , thanks for the explanation

Comment: my issue with these one Sir , is even I did assign this.reportFilter.masterBrokerName  = null , the select All checkbox is still currently checked